# How to unlock a part of library?

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to add some methods/make some changes inside locked library. Turns out the library does not fulfill user(mine) requirements, and I want to midifiy it. How can I unlock it?

Comment: import the files of library into your project and feel free to modify it. Double check license agreement before modifying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's open source and you follow the rules of the license you can clone it and edit it in whatever way you desire,

But if it's not open source or the license does not allow you to make changes your only option is to contact the author and request them or a permission to make changes or ask them to make the changes on their own.

If both options can't be achieved you can or find another library or do illegal actions.

Comment: I wanted to do this tutorial to allow me do windowsAuthentication https://suhas1989.wordpress.com/2015/01/28/ntlm-authentication-in-android/ , but I don't know how to get to these classes which should be modified

Comment: Are the classes(Source code) accessible online?

Comment: MIT license, I've found Transport package here: https://github.com/simpligility/ksoap2-android/tree/master/ksoap2-base/src/main/java/org/ksoap2

Comment: http://simpligility.github.io/ksoap2-android/license-information.html This is the license information and because the source is online you can clone and edit it, just verify that you can publish it properly

Comment: Looks like MIT license allow to do almost everything with it. But I am still wondering how to exctract classes from libreries.

Comment: Make a local copy of the files on your computer